# downloading million images in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jpeg

Am working on a project where am creating some urls and then from those urls am getting images.

for example I have an array object as `urls`

```
['abc.com/01.jpg',
'abc.com/01.jpg',
.......
]
```

and so on Urls like that..

What I am trying to do is to get images from those url and trying to save them through this code

```
download = (uri, filename, callback) ->
  request.head uri, (err, res, body) ->
    # console.log 'content-type:', res.headers['content-type']
    # console.log 'content-length:', res.headers['content-length']
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on 'close', callback
    return
  return
```

But its not working properly. Any body have some good ideas about downlaoding images from url in a nodeJS project?

Or may be not saving them locally but to upload them to Dropbox after getting from the url?

I got this error from above code

```
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\graby\image.jpg'
  at Error (native)

 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Because javascript is asynchronous, you have just asked you script to download 1 million jpg's at exactly the same time.  Ideally you want to maybe download say 10 files concurrently.  The exact number you might want to test.  Because too many even if it could be handled would cause something called thrashing, that would slow things down rather than making faster.

Comment: What could be the best approach you would suggest for this?

Comment: Just keep a count of active connections,. So you would first maybe start off 10 connections, every time a connection was complete, start the next one.

Comment: Can't we just do like give the system a pause for some time? when its downloading one image then pause and so on?

Comment: Pausing won't help here..  And ideally surely you want this thing going as fast as possible.  Download 10 files or maybe more, if the website your downloading from has high latency should not cause Node any problems.

Comment: It should be trivial to do a count, all you do is say start 10 requests, and then on your callback, just start another.  This should keep 10 requests constantly going.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open streams (files) for all these files in parallel but the OS limits the streams of your application.

You either can try downloading files synchronously, one after the other or you can try to batch the downloads, therefore always trying to download like 30 images in parallel.

Comment: how to do one after the other please give some example or any reference

Comment: @JunaidFarooq Request offers no such feature AFAIK so you could create a function to dispatch a download if there are URLs left and call this function from the download callback.